How to reference a struct in GLSL?
C++-style references can make code much neater but GLSL doesn't have them.
eg. This code:
for (int i=0; i<numCascades; ++i) {
    if (eyeDistance < shadow.cascade[i].end) {
        vec3 sc = eyePos*shadow.cascade[i].transform;

        // ...many more references to "shadow.cascade[i]" here

    }
}

Would be much neater if I could type this instead:
for (int i=0; i<numCascades; ++i) {
    const ShadowCascade& cascade = shadow.cascade[i];
    if (eyeDistance < cascade.end) {
        vec3 sc = eyePos*cascade.transform;

        // ...many more references to "cascade" here

    }
}

I could type this instead (same as above but no '&'):
for (int i=0; i<numCascades; ++i) {
    const ShadowCascade cascade = shadow.cascade[i];
    if (eyeDistance < cascade.end) {
        vec3 sc = eyePos*cascade.transform;

        // ...many more references to "cascade" here

    }
}

Would there be a performance penalty for that? Will the cascade struct be copied into a local variable (like in C++)?
How do people neaten this sort of code in GLSL? (Use #define? (ugh!))

In general yes, the cascade struct will be copied into the local like in C++. However a good optimizer might be able to see through it (with the help of the const) and optimize the copy out. Regarding using #define - it is replaced by the preprocessor before compilation, so I don't see how it is relevant for performance.

To answer my own question: I did some informal testing and using #define as shown below gave me a measurable improvement in frame rate.
for (int i=0; i<numCascades; ++i) {
    #define cascade shadow.cascade[i]
    if (eyeDistance < cascade.end) {
        vec3 sc = eyePos*cascade.transform;

        // ... more references to "cascade" here

    }
}

This was on desktop NVIDIA so I guess if they aren't optimizing that pattern then nobody else will be.

I think the indent of the #define adds a bit of semantic information but should I #undef it afterwards? Decisions, decisions...

Yes, you're right, you can't create a reference, or a pointer in GLSL in the way you could in C++.
In your last example, you copy the whole struct (const ShadowCascade cascade = shadow.cascade[i];). But do you? In compiler theory, there is an optimization technique called copy propagation. It means, that when you access cascade.transform, you'll get the same value as if you were to access shadow.cascade[i].transform. Why? Because you copied your struct, and haven't changed either struct since then. And if it chooses shadow.cascade[i].transform all the time, the variable cascade is never used, so it can eliminate the initialization and the copy. So in theory the compiler can figure out that if it uses the original array all the time, it doesn't have to copy the struct.
However, when you use for example glCompileShader, you use the compiler in your driver. Nvidia, AMD, and Intel have different compilers, maybe different driver versions contain different compilers, and maybe they work differently with different GPUs. So it's hard to tell if the compiler uses this optimization, or not. My advice is to compile your GLSL shaders to SPIR-V. It's similar to C#'s IL, or Java's Java bytecode. It is an architecture-neutral intermediate language. This way, after you compiled your shaders, you can examine the result, and check if the copy is there or not. SPIR-V has a lot of other advantages, like reducing runtime compilation time (since compiling from SPIR-V to machine code is faster than from GLSL).
But, SPIR-V is not available everywhere. It's always available in Vulkan, in OpenGL 4.6, and in OpenGL ES 3.2. it's usually available in older OpenGL, and OpenGL ES versions with an extension, but it's never available on the web. The solution that works everywhere is a macro, (as you mentioned). At the university, where I studied programming, professors said that macros are evil. And yes, it's not that hard to use macros and other preprocessor directives wrong. However, later, when I worked as a graphics programmer, I saw that people use these things a lot, because sometimes there is no real alternative to it, or this is the most performant. So while I understand that you're hesitant to use macros, and you definitely shouldn't use them for everything, I don't think that it's a problem to write something like this: #define CASCADE(i) shadow.cascade[i]. It'll work with all GLSL versions, with all vendors, drivers, you don't have to deal with SPIR-V, etc.
In summary, I advise you to use SPIR-V, macros, or both.

I have another doubt with macros though, will it calculate the array offset ("shadow.cascade[i]") every time I access a uniform. That needs to multiply i by the size of the struct, add an offset, etc. Will that be optimized away? It's all very annoying to have to just "trust the compiler".

I'd think the use of "const" would help the copy propagation optimization.

Well, probably it won't compute the array item's pointer multiple times. There is another optimization method compilers often use, which is called common subexpression elimination. If the compiler finds the same expression, like accessing an array item multiple times, it only evaluates it once.  Yeah, it's annoying that some compilers might do it, while others might not. But again, if you compile your shader to SPIR-V, you can see all the resulting operations and check if it's optimized.
